# How to post aspx page parameter in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I post parameters of aspx page to aspx method. Not in MVC controller method. Here is my view which name is ViewController.ascx:

```
        <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <script runat="server">

            protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
     string postData = String.Empty;

            postData += "pan=" + txtCardNumber.Text + "&";
}

</head>
<body>
    <form id="paymentForm" runat="server">
    <center>
 <table class="tableClass">
            <tr class="trHeader">
                <td>
                    Kredi Kartı Numarası:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="20" AutoCompleteType="None"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCreditCardNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCardNumber"
                        Display="Dynamic" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="buttonClass" Text="Gönder" CausesValidation="true"
                        OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I post data my parameters go to controller action method how can I send these parameters to aspx method?

Comment: I don't understand, you are using MVC? If yes, then you are joking :)

Comment: Yeap I'm using MVC of course you can't understand if you know why sometimes we need to use aspx page in MVC, now I'm getting answer my question from you

Comment: I have not had need to do this before, so good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in a hybrid project that uses both webforms and MVC then to ignore the requests to aspx pages, you have to define an ignore route in Global.asax.cs.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
```

before mapping all the routes.